# Calling a webapi method from Blazor server

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclient, blazor-server-side

It seems like this is deprecated and cannot be found in nuget package

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient

```
         public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
            {
                private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

                public EmployeeService(HttpClient httpClient)
                {
                    this.httpClient = httpClient;
                }

                public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployees()
                {
                    return await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Employee[]>("api/employees");
                }
            }
```

I am trying to call a webapi method from Blazor using httpClient.

What is the substitute for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your taget framework version. Just try to add `System.Net.Http.Json` namespace to check if it works or not.

If not working, you can use `GetFromJsonAsync` like below:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;  //be sure add this namespace..

public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployees()
{
    return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Employee[]>("https://localhost:portNumber/api/employees");
}
```

Comment: I am using .net framework 5

Comment: No, it is impossible with .net framework if you use blazor. It must be .net core. I think you may use .Net 5. So do you check my shared code? It should be work because I use .Net 5. Please copy my code to your project.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial many people have sourced their code from has a mistype - should be:

*return await httpClient.GetJson**From**Async<Employee[]>("api/employees");*